# How to swith to specific traffic light phase in Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I have an T-type intersection, working by using traffic light. But I don't want one of the roads to be full of cars. So I want to change traffic light phase to specific one to reduce amount of cars.

I have a varible "CarWaiting" that counts the amount of cars.
And an Condition triggered event where Condition is "CarWaiting > 2". But what should I write in "Action" section in Event to change traffic light phase?

Comment: this might help:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0dL3zFfO38U